# SwiperCore: how to dynamically import?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

How to dynamically import SwiperCore?

Can't find an appropriate import path when using import('path').then(() => {})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
import from 'swiper/esm/components/core/core-class'
```